# Single selection of radio button in Radiogroup android

Tags: android

This is my first post on this website and i hope it is well done. I am trying to have a single selection in my radiogroup but all of them get selected and cannot be unchecked. I want if one radio button is selected, the others remain unchecked. Here is my code so far.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {  
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

        for (int i = 1; i <= repItem.length; i++) {  
            final RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);  
            rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);  
            rdbtn.setText(repItem[i-1]);  
            ll.addView(rdbtn);  

            final RadioButton rd=new RadioButton(this);  
            rdbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
            {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View v)  
                {  
                    unCheckOther(rd, rdbtn.getId());  
                }  

                private void unCheckOther(RadioButton rd, int id)  
                {  
                    for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {  
                        for (int i = 1; i <= repItem.length; i++) {  
                            int butId=((row * 2) + i);  
                            if(butId != id)  
                            {  
                                rd.setChecked(false);  
                            }  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
            });  


        }  
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupchoi)).addView(ll);  
    }
```

Kind regards

Comment: Add the RadioButtons to a RadioGroup and it will be handled for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) instead of a `LinearLayout` as the container. It will take care of the mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `RadioGroup`. I see you have used a `linearLayout` and add all radio buttons into that. that's not what you want. you can just simply change that linear layout to `RadioGroup`.